# VS Code debugger shows infinitely deep PyTorch Tensor

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, pytorch, tensor

I'm working through some PyTorch code (not mine) in the VS Code debugger and it has this weird property that some (but not all) tensors have this infinite recursion property, [pictured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ano7O.png). Has anyone encountered this before? Is it a VS Code bug or a strange property of the tensor itself? The code works as expected.

Comment: Could you provide some more details regarding where you are getting the issue?